# How to loop through an array and run a Grunt task passing each value in the array as a Grunt option

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, frontend

I have an array similar to the following:

```
var themes = grunt.option('themes') || [
    'theme1',
    'theme2',
    'theme3'
];
```

And another variable:

```
var theme = grunt.option('theme') || 'theme1';
```

This value is used in various places in my grunt file for things such as determining the path to some assets etc.

To cut a long story short, I run the following command to compile the assets for a single theme:

```
grunt compile --theme=theme2
```

I'm looking for a way to loop through the array of themes and run the `compile` grunt task with the appropriate grunt.option. Essentially, what I'm looking to achieve would be the equivalent of this:

```
grunt compile --theme=theme1 && grunt compile --theme=theme2 && grunt compile --theme=theme3
```

I have tried the following:

```
grunt.registerTask('compile:all', function() {
    themes.forEach(function(currentTheme) {
        grunt.option('theme', currentTheme);
        grunt.task.run('compile');
    });
});
```

This runs the `compile` task the appropriate number of times, but the `theme` option doesn't seem to get set. So my Scss files get generated, but they are empty.

I've also tried this:

```
grunt.registerTask('compile:all', function() {
    themes.forEach(function(currentTheme) {
        grunt.util.spawn({
            grunt : true,
            args  : ['compile', '--theme=' + currentTheme]
        });
    });
});
```

The task finishes almost instantly with a "success" message, but it doesn't appear to do anything.

The last thing I've tried is similar to the above, except I attempt to use async:

```
grunt.registerTask('compile:all', function() {
    themes.forEach(function(currentTheme) {
        var done = grunt.task.current.async();
        grunt.util.spawn({
            grunt : true,
            args  : ['compile', '--theme=' + currentTheme]
        }, done);
    });
});
```

But this task fails. I'm not really sure where I'm going wrong,

Thanks for any help

Comment: Could you share an example of how the `theme` option is used?

Comment: For example in the JS concat task: `dest: theme + '/app.js'`

Really just used to determine directory paths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem is that your individual compile tasks are getting queued-up by `grunt.task.run('compile');`, but, by the time they execute, your `themes.forEach` loop has completed and your `theme` option is set to the last value in `themes`.

I think you will need to register a separate task that is responsible for setting the `theme` option *and* running the compile task.

```
grunt.registerTask('compile_theme', function (theme) {
    grunt.option('theme', theme);
    grunt.task.run('compile');
});
```

You would enqueue this task within your `compile:all` task for each of your themes:

```
themes.forEach(function(currentTheme) {
    grunt.task.run('compile_theme:' + currentTheme);
});
```

If you want to be able to specify at the command-line which themes to compile, you would need to update your `compile:all` task to read all `--theme=` parameters and enforce that the value is an array:

```
grunt.registerTask('compile:all', function () {
    var compileThemes = grunt.option('theme') || 'theme1';

    if (grunt.util.kindOf(compileThemes) === 'string') {
        compileThemes = [compileThemes];
    }

    compileThemes.forEach(function(currentTheme) {
        grunt.task.run('compile_theme:' + currentTheme);
    });
});
```

You would call the command as follows:

```
grunt compile:all // compiles 'theme1'
grunt compile:all --theme=theme2 // compiles 'theme2'
grunt compile:all --theme=theme2 --theme=theme3 // compiles 'theme2' and 'theme3'
```

Note: You would probably want to rename your `compile:all` task at this point because it no longer necessarily compiles *all* themes.

**EDIT**

It is not working because we are expecting too much of the `theme` option. We are trying to use this to get the themes entered at the command-line *and* to compose values dynamically in our configuration (like, `dest: theme + '/app.js'`. With the way I have structured my answer, `theme` cannot be used in the configuration.

I would instead use a configuration variable for `theme` that will be used in the config. This would mean updating the `compile_theme` task:

```
grunt.registerTask('compile_theme', function (theme) {
    grunt.config('theme', theme);
    grunt.task.run('compile');
});
```

We would need to update our configuration by substituting template strings for `theme`. For example:

```
dest: '<%= theme %>/app.js'
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. It really looks as though this should be right, but after trying it out I appear to be experiencing the same issues as the first example I gave, i.e. the compile tasks runs the correct number of times, but quicker than it should, resulting in empty .scss files, suggesting the `theme` option is still not being set.

Answer (score 2):

Using for each never worked for me, but this did based off of this help doc from grunt:
https://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks#multi-tasks

I added the list to my initConfig, ie

```
grunt.initConfig({
    run_themes: {
        theme1: 'sdi',
        theme2: 'syd',
        theme3: 'phl'
    }});
```

Then:

```
//register task to loop through the themes
grunt.task.registerMultiTask('run_themes', 'Compile themes.', function() {
    //grunt.themes.writeln(this.target + ': ' + this.data);
    grunt.log.writeln(this.target + ': ' + this.data);
    grunt.option('theme', this.data);
    grunt.task.run('sass');
});
```

And my sass definition makes use of grunt.option('theme') like this to put a copy of the same compiled css in each theme directory like sdi/default/... syd/default... phl/default...

```
// compile our sass to css
sass: {
    // sass compilation for "dev", unminified files
    dev: {
        options: {
            style: 'expanded'
        },
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd:'shared-resources/css/sass',
            src: ['*.scss', 'standalone/*.scss'],
            dest: "../<%= grunt.option('theme') %>/default/template-resources/css/dev",
            ext: '.css'
        }]
    }},
```

Comment: Thanks for the input here - this is really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the `forEach` method to build out a series of tasks, push the tasks to a task array instead of running within the `forEach` block:

```
grunt.registerTask('buildAll', function() {
    var tasks = [];
    themes.forEach(function(currentTheme) {
        tasks.push('compile:' + currentTheme);
    });

    grunt.tasks.run(tasks);
});
```

Within your `compile` task, you can pass `currentTheme` to the task using `this.args[0]` for normal tasks, or `this.target` for multitasks:

```
grunt.registerTask('compile', function() {
    var theme = this.args[0];  // sets local variable for use within task.
    grunt.option('theme', this.args[0]);  //sets option that can be referenced within this instance of `compile` 
});
```